# Show or hide report based on expression

Tags: reporting-services, business-intelligence

Today i have one problem with SSRS reports while show or hide report based on expression i tried different expects but it is still not working following is my expression.

`=IIf(Parameters!P_Level.Value = "3", true, false)`

I tried following another expression

```
=IIf(Parameters!P_Level.Value = 3, true, false)
```

Also tried

```
 =IIf(Parameters!P_Level.Value > 2, true, false)
```

but when i select parameter P_Level with value 3 still report is not displaying my report.

Please add in comment if you need any more details.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: What Component you want to show or hide ?? Rectangle , textbox , tablix ? (What hide Report ?)

Comment: I want to use it with chart and i set visibility as showorhide based on expression

Comment: This properties is "Hidden"  if you want to display report when p_Value = 3 use this Expr '=IIf(Parameters!P_Level.Value = 3, false, true)'

Comment: What is the name of the property that you are putting this expression in?